# mysql - finding latest service number

Tags: mysql

[image]

My expected output:
[image]

And I write like below:

```
SELECT c.cID, s.svcID, s.svcNote
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN service s ON s.cID = c.cID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(s.svcID) AS svcID
           FROM service s
           GROUP BY s.cID) AS s1 ON s1.svcID = s.svcID
ORDER BY c.cJoinDate DESC
```

However, I can't get my expected output and taking very long time to run my query. Can someone help me?

Comment: Change the left joins to inner join

Comment: Concerning performance: remember to create indexes on columns used in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` clauses and check that these are used by outputting the query planners results. (Though if your tables really are only as small as posted here, this won't be the cause of your performance issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only those entries with service, you need to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` will list all records in `Company`, including `cID = 4`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT c.cID, s.svcID, s.svcNote
FROM company c
INNER JOIN service s ON s.cID = c.cID
WHERE s.ID = (SELECT MAX(s2.svcID)
              FROM service s2
              WHERE s1.svcID = s2.svcID
              GROUP BY s2.cID)
ORDER BY c.cJoinDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cID, MAX(s.svcID), s.svcNote
FROM company c
INNER JOIN service s ON s.cID = c.cID
GROUP BY s.cID
ORDER BY c.cJoinDate DESC
```

Comment: An answer with just code is not very helpful. Please add an explanation of how this code works and why it is a good answer.

Comment: As per requirement we need max svcID we enter it in select clause now we using inner join it will give you only that records which having a company it can be left but it will return all services may be having a company or may deleted and group by is for unique record of each company with max svcID. if you have any query please comment for more clearance.